# Java, need help creating a method to select a specific element in an array

Tags: java, arrays, select, command

I have several commands created to ask a user to add numbers to an array.  I now need to be able to have the user select a specific element in the array and place an * on the selected element when printed out.  I have the program separated into two classes: one class for storing and managing the array and the other handles user input and output.

For example here is the code in the class that handles input/output:

```
else if (cmd.equals("add"))
        {
            // add x command
            int x = input.nextInt();
            list.add(x);
            list.print();
        }
```

and here is the part in the class that deals with the array:

```
public void add(int x)
{
    // Expand the list capacity if necessary
    if (count >= list.length)
    {
        // Allocate a new longer list
        int[] newList = new int[list.length + 5];

        // Copy existing numbers to new list
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
        {
            newList[i] = list[i];
        }

        // Reassign the list to be the new one
        list = newList;
    }

    // Add x to the end of the list
    list[count] = x;
    count++;
}
```

This is the command created to add entries to the array(and enlarge the array if necessary), now I just need help creating a command to allow a user to select a specific entry in the array and place an * in front of it.

Comment: Since it's an `int` array, you're not going to be able to add a "*" in front of anything.  You could keep track of the selected index and when required to print it, insert the "*" into the output

Comment: Good to know, im mostly just at a loss on how to create the command to select a specific index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prompt the user, then read in and store the selected index in a variable.  Do a check in your printing for-loop.

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the index of an element:");
int selectedElement = kb.nextInt();
```

Then when printing..

`for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
       if(i == selectedElement)
       // and then print out the * in front of it
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always print out the array, using the index to display which value you are displaying. You could also display it as index + 1, so it's more user-friendly (that way, the user isn't wondering why the numbering starts at 0). For example (this would be what the output might look like):

`1) First value.`

`2) Second value.`

`3) Third value.`

`Please enter the number that you would like to print out, then press enter.`

Once the user enters a value, you can subtract 1 from it to get the index of the array, and then print it out appropriately.

I hope I understood your question correctly, and I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried to make sense out your answer but it is not clear what you try to convey to me.

Comment: It would just be a matter of printing the array out to the user, allowing the user to enter an index that they would like to print, and printing out the array as a list with a * next to the chosen index.